# Initialize class with constructor in <jsp:useBean>

Tags: jsp, usebean

I am trying to initialize a class by passing a parameter to the constructor. I need the scope to be "page". I know I have one argument in my constructor, but how do I have one that accepts parameter using `<jsp:useBean>`, and can be called from a JSP page?

```
 public class A extends B {
    A(ServletRequest req) {
       super(req);
}
```

If there are no-arg constructor, We can use `< jsp:useBean id="someId" class="mypackage.A" scope="page" />` tag. But in a useBean JSP tag, you can't invoke any constructor.

Is there any way initialize class with constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Either use `<jsp:setProperty>`,

```
<jsp:useBean id="someId" class="mypackage.A" scope="page">
    <jsp:setProperty name="someId" property="request" value="${pageContext.request}" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

or use a normal servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("someId", new A(request));
```

It's by the way surprising that you tagged `[servlets]` on the question while that's usually not to be used together with `<jsp:useBean>` as those two approaches of managing beans are conflicting (one is MVC level 1 and other is MVC level 2). For detail, see also [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Nonetheless, having a bean property of `HttpServletRequest` type is fishy. There are undoubtedly better ways to achieve [the concrete functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).